# rock paper scissors at code academy

Tags: javascript

I am learning how to use javascript online at www.codeacademy.com and I made this game where you play rock paper scissors with a computer. Every time I try to run it, I get the same problem that says `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of script`, but I can't find the problem.

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
 computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
 computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
 computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1,choice2) 
{
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return("The result is a tie!")
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "scissors"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
        "scissors wins";
    }
    
console.log(compare(userChoice,computerChoice)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) 
{
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return("The result is a tie!")
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "scissors"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
        "scissors wins";
        }
    }
}
```

You are missing the last two brackets.